# Writing a pandas dataframe from a sagemaker to AWS S3 file

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to write from a sagemaker jupyter notebook into my S3 bucket. Found a solution which worked for me some time but now fails (not sure if it's due to recent package-updates?)

```
import io
import boto3
pickle_buffer = io.BytesIO()
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

df.to_pickle(pickle_buffer, compression=None)
s3_resource.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=pickle_buffer.getvalue())
```

This throws an error on this part of the line:
----> 8 pickle_buffer.getvalue())

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Anyone an idea why the buffer is closed? It should stay open....

Seems even my problem is independent of AWS:
Same error happens here:

```
import io

pickle_buffer = io.BytesIO()
df.to_pickle(pickle_buffer, compression=None)
pickle_buffer.getvalue()
```

Thanks
Oliver